# How can we arrive at the approximation $\tanh (x)\approx 1-e^{-2 a}$, for $x^2=a^2+\delta$ with $a>1$ and $\delta\to 0$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, hyperbolic-functions

I have seen somewhere that if we have $x^2=a^2+\delta$, where $a>1$ and $\delta\rightarrow0$, then we can use this approximation
$$ \tanh (x)\approx 1-e^{-2 a} $$
Can someone explain how we can arrive at this relation?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $1-2e^{-2a}$, which is what you would get for $a\gg 1$?  (Assuming $x>0$ of course, or else you get the wrong sign).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}} \approx 1-e^{-2x}$ for large $x$ and that $\tanh(x)\approx\tanh(a)$ for small $\delta$.

*Edit*: Taking into account the comment above and below in fact the approximation $1-2e^{-2a}$ seems to be more appropriate. It can be justified by   using the first two terms of the Taylor series for $\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ with $y=e^{-2a}$.

Comment: How can you ignore $e^{-2x}$ with respect to $1$ in the denominator and not in the numerator? Doesn't seem like justice.

Comment: I don't know why a downvote. Your edit makes things very clear. $\to +1$.